# Running 'join' bash utility under PHP shell_exec from Cygwin

Tags: php, bash, unix, cygwin

I am using cygwin cmd application to execute join utility.

From cygwin:

```
$ join -v 1 <(sort C:/inetpub/wwwroot/webclient/database_sequences/refseqgene_1.txt) <(sort C:/inetpub/wwwroot/webclient/database_sequences/refseqgene_2.txt) > C:/inetpub/wwwroot/webclient/database_sequences/result.txt
```

It is working and generates result file successfully.

Now, I want to type this command from my php code.

I try:

```
shell_exec("C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe --login -c 'join -v 1 <(sort $text_files_path/$OldDatabaseFile.txt) <(sort $text_files_path/$NewDatabaseFile.txt) > $text_files_path/result.txt 2>&1'");
```

but, it does not create `result.txt`

I was using diff in the same php and it was working

```
shell_exec("C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe --login -c 'diff $text_files_path/$OldDatabaseFile.txt $text_files_path/$NewDatabaseFile.txt >  $text_files_path/DelSeqGi_$OldDatabaseFile$NewDatabaseFile.txt 2>&1'");
```